# Returning the first item from a sub-list, if any, null if empty

Tags: java, arraylist

> My working out so far, i get indexOutOfBoundsException error

```
public static Integer firstSubListItem(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list) {
        if(list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } 
        return list.get(0).get(0);
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to check if `list.get(0)` is null or empty as well. Just because the outer List isn't null doesn't mean that the elements it contains are all Lists with at least 1 element.

Comment: oh yeah right got it now, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a check on `list.get(0)`

```
public static Integer firstSubListItem(List<List<Integer>> list) {
    if (list == null || list.isEmpty() || list.get(0).isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return list.get(0).get(0);
}
```

```
System.out.println(firstSubListItem(Arrays.asList()));                    // null
System.out.println(firstSubListItem(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList())));     // null
System.out.println(firstSubListItem(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1, 2)))); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a check that the list returned by `list.get(0)` isn't `null` or empty:

```
public static Integer firstSubListItem(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list) {
    if  (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } 

    List<Integer> list0 = list.get(0);
    if (list0 == null || list0.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return list0.get(0);
}
```